# Page is loading infinitely in safari <=8 browsers

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari

[image]

Hi All,

Am getting the attached error in console only for safari <=8 versions.
Please let me know your findings

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=performance

Answer (score 0):

This because it's not supported by older Version of Browsers.

check this [site](http://caniuse.com/#search=performance) before you try adding 3rd party tools to your site

Comment: Thanks. But for other pages also there are same exception"window.performance.timing", but those pages are working fine.
am concerned about the other two errors, "refused to get unsafe header X-Region"

Comment: those are being thrown because you try to Access Content from another domain.